# Javascript Regex with & without attributes

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple replace string with the help of regex. I want to add a new attribute such as `"isElm"` in every `<p>` tag. Please refer the below fiddle. If I use regex as `/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g` and use replace, it works, but if the `<p>` tag has an attribute, it does not. However, if I use this regex: `/<p([^>]*)>(.*?)<\/p>/g`, the replace with attribute works, but without the `<p>` tag, it does not work. I want to find a generic solution for this. Below are the two cases:

1. `<p>one</p>` should change to `<p isElm="true">one</p>`
2. `<p id='2'>two</p>` should change to `<p id="2" isElm="true">`

Note that for both cases above, the `isElm="true"` attribute is added after the replace. I do not want to create a DOM or jQuery object. I have to use regex due to some limitations.

Fiddle Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/9VHtR/1/

Comment: Stop for a moment and read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans. Then format your inline code accordingly.

Comment: I just realize I was doing the formatting but since you where doing it i could not save edits. will take care in futuer

Comment: FYI, you didn't include a jsFiddle example, even though you reference it (you added a link, but that was to http://jsfiddle.net/, so I removed it).

Comment: [Do not try to parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) Use the DOM instead (when working with JS, you usually already have one). Btw, `isElm` is not a valid HTML attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're overcomplicating it (probably matching whole `<p>` is your requirement) but you can accomplish your task like follows

```
var x = '<p>this is text</p>';
x = x.replace('<p', '<p isElm="true" ');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Ejay that is the hardcode & is not generic. It was a space issue I just realize in regex I thought I have to add "or" operator which I was not sure of how to do that. If someone interested can look at it, with updated fiddle all p tags with & without attribute anywhere in string will be added new attribute "isElm". Fiddle Link => http://jsfiddle.net/9VHtR/1/